# Swift generics in protocol: operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'Self.T'

Tags: swift, generics, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

I'm trying to build a simple observer mixin with Swift 2.
Here comes just the relevant part.

```
protocol Observable{

    typealias T 
    var observers:[T] { get set }
    mutating func removeObserver(observer:T)
}
```

To create the mixin I use an extension:

```
extension Observable{

    mutating func removeObserver(observer:T){
        let index = self.observers.indexOf{ $0 === observer }
        if let _ = index{
            self.observers.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }   
}
```

This creates the compiler error: `Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'Self.T'`

Can you explain to me why this error is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "identical-to" operator `===` can only be applied to *reference*
types, i.e. instances of a `class`. One possible solution is to 
restrict the generic type `T` to `AnyObject` (the protocol to which
all classes implicitly conform):

```
protocol Observable {

    typealias T : AnyObject
    var observers:[T] { get set }
    mutating func removeObserver(observer:T)
}

extension Observable {

     mutating func removeObserver(observer:T) { 
        if let index = (self.observers.indexOf { $0 === observer }) {
            self.observers.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }   
}
```

Alternatively, restrict `T` to `Equatable` types (which means that
a `==` operator must be defined for the type):

```
protocol Observable {

    typealias T : Equatable
    var observers:[T] { get set }
    mutating func removeObserver(observer:T)
}

extension Observable {

     mutating func removeObserver(observer:T) { 
        if let index = self.observers.indexOf(observer) {
            self.observers.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I accepted it, because it is obviously the answer to my question :) Sadly, it doesn't solve my problem completely.

Let's say I define a `protocol` `Observer` that implements `AnyObject`. Next I create a class `ConcreteObservable` that implements `Observable`. I define `typealias T = Observer`.

I get the following error:
`Type 'ConcreteObservable' does not conform to protocol 'Observable'`
`Protocol requires nested type 'T'` and `Possibly intended match 'T' (aka 'Observer') does not conform to 'AnyObject'`

Any ideas of how to fix that?

Comment: @hendra: You have to make your class generic: `class ConcreteObservable<T : Observer> : Observable { ... }`.

Comment: Hm this doesn't really make sense to me. If I define this class as generic like you sad, I would need to declare a concrete type of an `Observer` during initialization of `ConcreteObservable`. But any object that conforms to `Observer` should be able to observe my `ConcreteObservable`. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: @hendra: The problem is that the `Observable` protocol does not *conform* to `AnyObject` even if it inherits from that protocol: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself, perhaps that helps.

Comment: Does `Observable` protocol really need to define, how should i store the `Observer`'s ? @MartinR